# Contact future employer

Tags: new-job, job-offer, email

I want to thank my future employer for offering me the job. I know there are a lot of example letters on the internet but my situation is different. I accepted the job 2 weeks ago via a recruitment company  the requirement company just got back to me today with my employer's details.

Any ideas how to start the letter? Will it be a good idea to  Apologize for the late contact as i just got hold of his details?

Examples would be appreciated

This is what i have at the moment.

> Hi John,
>
> I would like to thank you for offering me the position of "position"
>   with open door company. I am pleased to accept this offer and really
>   looking forward to starting employment with "Company Name" on  "Date".
>
> Thank you again for this excellent career opportunity, and I look
>   forward to joining your organisation and contributing to the future
>   success of the team. If there is any further information or paperwork
>   you need me to complete, please let me know and I will arrange it as
>   soon as possible.

is this ok?

Comment: To them, this is in one ear and out the other.  They're actually in the mood to thank you for being able to help. Best thing to do is show your appreciation by solving their problems.

Comment: Naw, I think it's a nice gesture. Sure, for a big company it may not matter much, but it cant hurt. Make sure it sounds personal so it doesn't come off as a template mail you found on the internet.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience (in the US; YMMV) it would be unusual to send your future employer a plain thank-you letter.  So if you want to send a thank-you letter, you need to bundle it into a letter that accomplishes some other purpose.

You've already accepted the job (via the recruiter), according to your question.  So the purpose of this letter isn't to *accept* the offer, and the "pleased to accept" part of your draft letter might confuse them.  But you can use this letter to *ask a question that needs to be answered before your first day*, as hinted at by the end of your draft.

Consider something like this:

> Hi John,
>
> I'm looking forward to joining $company as a $position.  I've just received your information from $recruiter, who told me to arrive at your office on $date at $time.  Is there any paperwork I need to complete in advance, or anything special I need to bring with me on that day?
>
> Thank you for the opportunity. I look forward to working with you.

This letter confirms the important details, accounts for the delay (if that was a problem) without apologizing, and pre-empts problems like you not knowing that you needed to bring your passport for identity validation (that's just an example).

Answer (score 2):

> "Thank you again for this excellent career opportunity, and I look
>   forward to joining your organisation and contributing to the future
>   success of the team. "

You already state it in the previous paragraph, so leave it out.

Here is my short reply to a job offer that I accept.

> Hello xxx, Thank you so much for your job offer. I am really excited
>   to hear of your good news and looking forward to working for "Company
>   Name" on "Date". Have a good day! - userxxx

Comment: I think the current letter @Josh has so far is better than the one you propose.